# Does it matter after running "configure" and find a lot of missing dependencies when I build OpenJDK9 on Ubuntu?

Tags: java-8, jvm, java, java-9

System:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
```

JDK and JRE:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      manual mode
```

### Do I have to install all the dependencies that shows "no"?

```
username:~/sandboxJDK/jdk9$bash ./configure 
Running generated-configure.sh
configure: Configuration created at Thu Jun  8 23:03:30 CDT 2017.
configure: configure script generated at timestamp 1494858828.
checking for basename... /usr/bin/basename
checking for bash... /bin/bash
checking for cat... /bin/cat
checking for chmod... /bin/chmod
checking for cmp... /usr/bin/cmp
checking for comm... /usr/bin/comm
checking for cp... /bin/cp
checking for cut... /usr/bin/cut
checking for date... /bin/date
checking for gdiff... no
checking for diff... /usr/bin/diff
checking for dirname... /usr/bin/dirname
checking for echo... /bin/echo
checking for expr... /usr/bin/expr
checking for file... /usr/bin/file
checking for find... /usr/bin/find
checking for head... /usr/bin/head
checking for gunzip... /bin/gunzip
checking for pigz... no
checking for gzip... /bin/gzip
checking for ln... /bin/ln
checking for ls... /bin/ls
checking for mkdir... /bin/mkdir
checking for mktemp... /bin/mktemp
checking for mv... /bin/mv
checking for nawk... /usr/bin/nawk
checking for printf... /usr/bin/printf
checking for rm... /bin/rm
checking for rmdir... /bin/rmdir
checking for sh... /bin/sh
checking for sort... /usr/bin/sort
checking for tail... /usr/bin/tail
checking for gtar... no
checking for tar... /bin/tar
checking for tee... /usr/bin/tee
checking for touch... /usr/bin/touch
checking for tr... /usr/bin/tr
checking for uname... /bin/uname
checking for uniq... /usr/bin/uniq
checking for wc... /usr/bin/wc
checking for which... /usr/bin/which
checking for xargs... /usr/bin/xargs
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cygpath... no
checking for greadlink... no
checking for readlink... /bin/readlink
checking for df... /bin/df
checking for cpio... /bin/cpio
checking for nice... /usr/bin/nice
checking for pandoc... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking openjdk-build os-cpu... linux-x86_64
checking openjdk-target os-cpu... linux-x86_64
checking compilation type... native
checking for top-level directory... /home/xfwu/sandboxJDK/jdk9
checking if custom source is suppressed (openjdk-only)... no
checking which variant of the JDK to build... normal
checking which debug level to use... release
checking which variants of the JVM to build... server
checking for sysroot... 
checking for toolchain path... 
checking for extra path... 
checking where to store configuration... in default location
checking what configuration name to use... linux-x86_64-normal-server-release
checking for apt-get... apt-get
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... /usr/bin/make
configure: Testing potential make at /usr/bin/make, found using make in PATH
configure: Using GNU make at /usr/bin/make (version: GNU Make 4.1)
checking if make --output-sync is supported... yes
checking for output-sync value... none
checking if find supports -delete... yes
checking what type of tar was found... gnu
checking that grep (/bin/grep) -Fx handles empty lines in the pattern list correctly... yes
checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for ldd... /usr/bin/ldd
checking for otool... no
checking for greadelf... no
checking for readelf... /usr/bin/readelf
checking for dot... no
checking for hg... /usr/bin/hg
checking for stat... /usr/bin/stat
checking for time... /usr/bin/time
checking for dtrace... no
checking for gpatch... no
checking for patch... /usr/bin/patch
checking bash version... 4.3.48
checking if bash supports pipefail... yes
checking if bash supports errexit (-e)... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking headless only... no
checking for graphviz dot... no, cannot generate full docs
checking for pandoc... no, cannot generate full docs
checking full docs... no, missing dependencies
checking if packaged modules are kept... yes (default)
checking for version string... 9-internal+0-adhoc.xfwu.jdk9
configure: Found potential Boot JDK using JAVA_HOME
checking for Boot JDK... /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
checking Boot JDK version... openjdk version "1.8.0_131" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.10.2-b11) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode) 
checking for java in Boot JDK... ok
checking for javac in Boot JDK... ok
checking for javah in Boot JDK... ok
checking for jar in Boot JDK... ok
checking for jarsigner in Boot JDK... ok
checking if Boot JDK supports modules... no
checking if Boot JDK is 32 or 64 bits... 64
checking for Build JDK... yes, will use output dir
configure: Using default toolchain gcc (GNU Compiler Collection)
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking resolved symbolic links for CC... /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6
configure: Using gcc C compiler version 6.2.0 [gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005]
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... /usr/bin/g++
checking resolved symbolic links for CXX... /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-6
configure: Using gcc C++ compiler version 6.2.0 [g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005]
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /usr/bin/gcc -E
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /usr/bin/g++ -E
checking for ar... ar
configure: Rewriting AR to "/usr/bin/ar"
checking for strip... strip
configure: Rewriting STRIP to "/usr/bin/strip"
checking for nm... nm
configure: Rewriting NM to "/usr/bin/nm"
checking for gobjcopy... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
configure: Rewriting OBJCOPY to "/usr/bin/objcopy"
checking for gobjdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
configure: Rewriting OBJDUMP to "/usr/bin/objdump"
checking if the C compiler supports "-Og"... yes
checking if the C++ compiler supports "-Og"... yes
checking if both compilers support "-Og"... yes
checking if linker supports "-Wl,-z,relro"... yes
checking if linker supports "-Wl,-z,now"... yes
checking for broken SuSE 'ld' which only understands anonymous version tags in executables... no
checking for jtreg... no
checking for jtreg test harness... no, not found
checking if @file is supported by gcc... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking size of int *... 8
checking for target address size... 64 bits
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking if the C++ compiler supports "-std=gnu++98 -Werror"... yes
configure: GCC >= 6 detected; adding -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks and -fno-lifetime-dse
checking if the C++ compiler supports "-std=gnu++98 -Werror"... yes
configure: GCC >= 6 detected; adding -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks and -fno-lifetime-dse
checking if the C compiler supports "-m64"... yes
checking if the C++ compiler supports "-m64"... yes
checking if both compilers support "-m64"... yes
checking if native warnings are errors... yes (default)
checking if the C compiler supports "-Wno-this-is-a-warning-that-do-not-exist"... yes
checking if the C++ compiler supports "-Wno-this-is-a-warning-that-do-not-exist"... yes
checking if both compilers support "-Wno-this-is-a-warning-that-do-not-exist"... yes
checking if the C compiler supports "-Wno-this-is-a-warning-that-do-not-exist"... yes
checking if the C++ compiler supports "-Wno-this-is-a-warning-that-do-not-exist"... yes
checking if both compilers support "-Wno-this-is-a-warning-that-do-not-exist"... yes
checking what type of native debug symbols to use... zipped
checking for dtrace tool... not found, cannot build dtrace
checking sys/sdt.h usability... no
checking sys/sdt.h presence... no
checking for sys/sdt.h... no
checking if dtrace should be built... no, missing dependencies
checking if Hotspot gtest unit tests should be built... yes
checking if static link of stdc++ is possible... yes
checking how to link with libstdc++... static
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
checking for X11/extensions/shape.h... yes
checking for X11/extensions/Xrender.h... yes
checking for X11/extensions/XTest.h... yes
checking for X11/Intrinsic.h... yes
checking if XlinearGradient is defined in Xrender.h... yes
checking cups/cups.h usability... yes
checking cups/cups.h presence... yes
checking for cups/cups.h... yes
checking cups/ppd.h usability... yes
checking cups/ppd.h presence... yes
checking for cups/ppd.h... yes
checking for FREETYPE... yes
checking for freetype... yes (using pkg-config)
checking if we can compile and link with freetype... yes
checking if we should bundle freetype... no
checking for ALSA... yes
checking for which libjpeg to use... bundled
checking for which giflib to use... bundled
checking for which libpng to use... bundled
checking for compress in -lz... yes
checking for which zlib to use... system
checking for which lcms to use... bundled
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for ELF... yes
checking if libelf works... yes
checking if jdk.internal.vm.compiler should be built... yes
checking if aot should be enabled... yes
checking if elliptic curve crypto implementation is present... yes
checking if jtreg failure handler should be built... no, missing jtreg
checking if the CDS classlist generation should be enabled... yes
checking for number of cores... 64
checking for memory size... 128694 MB
checking for appropriate number of jobs to run in parallel... 64
checking flags for boot jdk java command ...  -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US 
checking flags for boot jdk java command for big workloads...  -Xms64M -Xmx1600M -XX:ThreadStackSize=1536
checking flags for bootcycle boot jdk java command for big workloads... -Xms64M -Xmx1600M -XX:ThreadStackSize=1536
checking flags for boot jdk java command for small workloads...  -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xms32M -Xmx512M -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1
checking whether to use sjavac... no
checking whether to use javac server... yes
checking If precompiled header is enabled... yes
checking that precompiled headers work... yes
checking is ccache enabled... no
checking if build directory is on local disk... yes
checking JVM features for JVM variant 'server'... all-gcs aot cds compiler1 compiler2 fprof graal jni-check jvmci jvmti management nmt services vm-structs
configure: creating /home/xfwu/sandboxJDK/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/configure-support/config.status
config.status: creating /home/xfwu/sandboxJDK/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/spec.gmk
config.status: creating /home/xfwu/sandboxJDK/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/bootcycle-spec.gmk
config.status: creating /home/xfwu/sandboxJDK/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/buildjdk-spec.gmk
config.status: creating /home/xfwu/sandboxJDK/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/compare.sh
config.status: creating /home/xfwu/sandboxJDK/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/Makefile

====================================================
The existing configuration has been successfully updated in
/home/xfwu/sandboxJDK/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release
using default settings.

Configuration summary:
* Debug level:    release
* HS debug level: product
* JDK variant:    normal
* JVM variants:   server
* OpenJDK target: OS: linux, CPU architecture: x86, address length: 64
* Version string: 9-internal+0-adhoc.xfwu.jdk9 (9-internal)

Tools summary:
* Boot JDK:       openjdk version "1.8.0_131" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.10.2-b11) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)  (at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64)
* Toolchain:      gcc (GNU Compiler Collection)
* C Compiler:     Version 6.2.0 (at /usr/bin/gcc)
* C++ Compiler:   Version 6.2.0 (at /usr/bin/g++)

Build performance summary:
* Cores to use:   64
* Memory limit:   128694 MB

WARNING: The result of this configuration has overridden an older
configuration. You *should* run 'make clean' to make sure you get a
proper build. Failure to do so might result in strange build problems.
```

### README-builds.html

In the official file, the suggested for Linux are

> Install all the software development packages needed including alsa,
>   freetype, cups, and xrender. See specific system packages.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to install these, unless you get a clear error message.

The `configure`script adapts the build to the concrete UNIX variant you are building on. For example if a library function is not natively available, it will compile in a replacement.